# How do I make it this OpenSSL command starts working?

Tags: php, openssl

My OpenSSL command is not working, which I am running through php's exec() function.

The error that is outputted is "1".

OpenSSL is enabled and working.

Here is the command:

```
$openssl_cmd = "($OPENSSL smime -sign -signer $MY_CERT_FILE -inkey $MY_KEY_FILE " .
                                    "-outform der -nodetach -binary <<_EOF_\n$data\n_EOF_\n) | " .
                                    "$OPENSSL smime -encrypt -des3 -binary -outform pem $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE";
                exec($openssl_cmd, $output, $error);
```

I am running the latest version of XAMPP and running on Windows 10.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is the full command when outputted as die($openssl_cmd); in php:

```
(C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.exe smime -sign -signer C:\xampp\[redacted]\paypal\pubcert.pem -inkey C:\xampp\[redacted]\paypal\prvkey.pem -outform der -nodetach -binary <<_EOF_ cmd=_xclick amount=[redacted] item_number=[redacted] discount_rate=0 item_name=[redacted] notify_url=https://www.REDACTED.net/paypal/ipn business=REDACTED cert_id=REDACTED currency_code=USD no_shipping=1 bn=domain.PHP_EWP2 _EOF_ ) | C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.exe smime -encrypt -des3 -binary -outform pem C:\xampp\[redacted]\paypal\paypal_cert.pem
```

EDIT:
I am using https://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php as a guide.

Comment: it works when you execute it from the Windows command line?

Comment: When I do this from the Windows command line, it outputs the command along with: << was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Your command would probably work on Linux... I don't believe you can do that it in windows although I think you can do piping using the Windows PowerShell

Comment: Oh that sounds good. How would I pipe it into the Windows PowerShell? Cheers!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/829776/how-to-use-powershell-command-in-cmd-pipe

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Did my comment help you to resolve the question?

Comment: Yes it did, thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a Linux-style command in Windows, something that uses piping and file redirection, it is possible to run the command using the Windows PowerShell.

For example, in this case, you would execute it via the PowerShell by executing something similar to this:

```
poewrshell -Command "(C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.exe smime -sign -signer C:\xampp\[redacted]\paypal\pubcert.pem -inkey C:\xampp\[redacted]\paypal\prvkey.pem -outform der -nodetach -binary <<_EOF_ cmd=_xclick amount=[redacted] item_number=[redacted] discount_rate=0 item_name=[redacted] notify_url=https://www.REDACTED.net/paypal/ipn business=tomekandres@live.ca cert_id=REDACTED currency_code=USD no_shipping=1 bn=domain.PHP_EWP2 _EOF_ ) | C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.exe smime -encrypt -des3 -binary -outform pem C:\xampp\[redacted]\paypal\paypal_cert.pem"
```